# Adding zoom functionality to jPCT scene

Tags: android, opengl-es, zooming, jpct

I would like to add zoom functionality to my scene. How would one do that?

This is my code at the moment:

```
private static float touchTurn = 0;
private static float touchTurnUp = 0;

private static float xpos = -1;
private static float ypos = -1;

static class ClearGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
    public ClearGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(myContext);
    }

@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
        if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            xpos = me.getX();
            ypos = me.getY();
            return true;
        }

        if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            xpos = -1;
            ypos = -1;
            touchTurn = 0;
            touchTurnUp = 0;
            return true;
        }

        if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            float xd = me.getX() - xpos;
            float yd = me.getY() - ypos;

            xpos = me.getX();
            ypos = me.getY();

            touchTurn = xd / 100f;
            touchTurnUp = yd / 100f;
            return true;
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(15);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Doesn't matter here...
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(me);
    }
}

static class MyRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

        private long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        public MyRenderer() {
        }

        public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h) {
            if (fb != null) {
                fb.dispose();
            }
            fb = new FrameBuffer(gl, w, h);

            if (master == null) {

                world = new World();
                world.setAmbientLight(20, 20, 20);

                sun = new Light(world);
                sun.setIntensity(250, 250, 250);

                try {
                    cube = loadModel(thingName, thingScale);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                cube.build();

                world.addObject(cube);

                Camera cam = world.getCamera();
                cam.moveCamera(Camera.CAMERA_MOVEOUT, 50);
                cam.lookAt(cube.getTransformedCenter());

                SimpleVector sv = new SimpleVector();
                sv.set(cube.getTransformedCenter());
                sv.y -= 100;
                sv.z -= 100;
                sun.setPosition(sv);
                MemoryHelper.compact();

                if (master == null) {
                    Logger.log("Saving master Activity!");
                    // master = fr;
                }
            }
        }

        public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        }

        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
            if (touchTurn != 0) {
                cube.rotateY(touchTurn);
                touchTurn = 0;
            }

            if (touchTurnUp != 0) {
                cube.rotateX(touchTurnUp);
                touchTurnUp = 0;
            }

            fb.clear(back);
            world.renderScene(fb);
            world.draw(fb);
            fb.display();

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - time >= 1000) {
                Logger.log(fps + "fps");
                fps = 0;
                time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            fps++;
        }
```

If you need more information let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase/decrease camera's fov.